# Wordpress JSON API returns normal site page in html. How do I get it to give me JSON like it's supposed to

Tags: json, wordpress

For example, entering `http://mywordpresswebsite.example.com/?json=1` into the browser loads the main site html, the same as omitting the json querystring variable: `http://mywordpresswebsite.example.com/`

The JSON API is activated.  I have tried reactivating and deactivating, checking .htaccess file settings, and deactivating all other plugins.  None of those have made much difference so far.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the new endpoint for Wordpress 4.7 is mywordpresswebsite.example.com/index.php/wp-json.  It's part of Wordpress Core as of 4.7 and not a plugin anymore, there's nothing to be activated.  Thank you, Mark Kaplun.

Comment: I'm still getting HTML back. Even after using the example you provided. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct:  
  `http://example.com/wordpressInstallFolderIfYouHaveOne/index.php/wp-json`

If that doesn't work, be sure you're on wordpress 4.7 or later by updating wordpress.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with my localhost test page and was wondering, why my route worked last week and was not accessible this week.

### Short explanation

After some tests and a lot of frustration, I was able to use the REST API Route again by following the wordpress documentation about [routes-vs-endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#routes-vs-endpoints) with [“Pretty Permalinks”](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#mod_rewrite-pretty-permalinks) and [“Ugly” Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#default-ugly)

### Longer explanation

I guess in my case it was based on the reinstall of my MySQL Database. By installing the new database, my previous setup has been reset to the wordpress standard installation with permalinks as "plain", which is an "ugly" permalink. That's the reason, why the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46576232/9620269) of Mattygabe work for me after the reinstall of the database.

But with this solution, I had a problem with my filter value and therefore I found the solution with "pretty premalinks" and changed my permalinks to "Month and name", as shown in the picture. After this change, I could access my REST API via the desired route.

[image]

There could be also some difficulties with REST APIs related to the following examples:

- using ["wp"](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#namespaces) within the REST route
- if you work on plugins, which should be shared, keep on mind that some plugins may restrict REST Access, e.g. [iThemes Security](https://ithemes.com/security/wordpress-rest-api-restrict-access/)

Comment: This is true, which makes it slightly challenging to develop features that rely on async REST API requests on the client side. At least there's a check that can be used to determine is a permalink structure is in place: https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#check-for-permalink-structure

Answer (score 6):

I'm likely doing it wrong, but when I form my requests for a Wordpress installation at `http://www.example.com/` like this:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?rest_route=/my/rest/route/here`

I end up getting proper responses back.

I had a heck of a time figuring this out and ended up grokking a URL formatted like that in the HTML returned to me. I was expecting to make requests as `http://www.example.com/wp_json/wp/v2/my/rest/route/here` , but I only got HTML responses.

(FWIW, I am reposting this on all similar questions on the StackExchange network. Admins/mods - if this is against the rules or seen as rep spamming, feel free to take it down. Was hoping to help anyone else hitting the same issue I am, and to also learn what it is I've done wrong and why.)

Answer (score 5):

I changed Permalinks (Settings => Permalinks)
[image]

Comment: The only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this issue. I did install the WP API plugin and then realized I didn't need it so I deactivated it and deleted it. Afterwards I tried a GET request to https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts and received the HTML of my wordpress site.

To fix this I ended up deactivating all plugins and then I started receiving the JSON response from https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts so I stepped through each plugin reactivating and in the end all my plugins are active and the endpoint is responding with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue returning html page instead of JSON response on Wordpress 5.3 and I got resolved when I changed the Permalink as Post name from plain